# Pipe delimiter file, but no pipe inside data

Tags: python

## Problem

I need to re-format a text from comma (`,`) separated values to pipe (`|`) separated values. Pipe characters within the values of the original (comma separated) text shall be replaced by a space for representation in the (pipe separated) result text.

The pipe separated result text shall be written back to the same file from which the original comma separated text has been read.

I am using python 2.6

## Possible Solution

I should read the file first and remove all pipes with spaces in that and later replace (`,`) with (`|`).

Is there a the better way to achieve this?

Comment: To those bugger who believes in down voting without giving explanation, go get a life. Requesting others to please comment below, let me know if I am asking anything which is possibly present in forum or not have given sufficient data

Comment: You could read the file line by line, then split on comma and replace each `|` within values obtained by the split, then just simply join modified values with `|`.

Comment: @mic4ael If I read the file and replace(,) with (|) then while checking the data which should not contain pipe will possible remove all pipes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the value-separated file parsing wheel. Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to do the parsing *and* the writing for you.

The `csv` module will add `"..."` quotes around values that contain the separator, so in principle you don't need to replace the `|` pipe symbols in the values. To replace the original file, write to a new (temporary) outputfile then move that back into place.

```
import csv
import os

outputfile = inputfile + '.tmp'
with open(inputfile, 'rb') as inf, open(outputfile, 'wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerows(reader)
os.remove(inputfile)
os.rename(outputfile, inputfile)
```

For an input file containing:

```
foo,bar|baz,spam
```

this produces

```
foo|"bar|baz"|spam
```

Note that the middle column is wrapped in quotes.

If you do need to replace the `|` characters in the values, you can do so as you copy the rows:

```
outputfile = inputfile + '.tmp'
with open(inputfile, 'rb') as inf, open(outputfile, 'wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow([col.replace('|', ' ') for col in row])
os.remove(inputfile)
os.rename(outputfile, inputfile)
```

Now the output for my example becomes:

```
foo|bar baz|spam
```

Comment: I am getting permission denied error, bcos i dont have permission to temp directory of system. Using windows with company security

Comment: @cyborg: then use a different temp directory; you can set `tempfile.tempdir` before running `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`.

Comment: @cyborg: or use `open(inputfile + '.tmp', 'wb')` as the temporary outputfile, then use `os.rename(inputfile + '.tmp', inputfile)` to move that file back over the old name.

Comment: @cyborg: I've updated the answer to use the latter approach; for this type of job it is probably just simpler.

Comment: The above code will give error that file already exist. I tried formatting the code but still error is there. ""Cannot create a file that already exists"". Opening file in that way gives error in python 2.6 so I tried nesting other open inside the first but same error

Comment: @cyborg: it means you already have a `.tmp` file there that hasn't been removed; perhaps due to a previous error?

Comment: I have changed code, and it worked fine. Thanks a lot and appreciate all your time.

Comment: @cyborg: ah, I sometimes forget that on Windows a rename doesn't allow you to remove the original. You could do a rename *first* (move input to temp) then open the temp filename and write to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to work with a variation of CSV - in that case, [Python's CSV library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) might as well be what you need. You can use it with custom delimiters and it will auto-handle escaping for you (this example was yanked from the manual and modified):

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    spamwriter.writerow(['One', 'Two', 'Three])
```

There are also ways to modify quoting and escaping and other options. Reading works similarly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary file from the original that has the pipe characters replaced, and then replace the original file with it when the processing is done:

```
import csv
import tempfile
import os

filepath = 'C:/Path/InputFile.csv'

with open(filepath, 'rb') as fin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    fout = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=os.path.dirname(filepath)
                                       delete=False)
    temp_filepath = fout.name
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')

#   writer.writeheader()  # requires Python 2.7
    header = dict(zip(reader.fieldnames, reader.fieldnames))
    writer.writerow(header)

    for row in reader:
        for k,v in row.items():
            row[k] = v.replace('|'. ' ')
        writer.writerow(row)
    fout.close()

os.remove(filepath)
os.rename(temp_filepath, filepath)
```

Comment: Do we have any method called as writeheader() ?

Comment: Please if you can suggest then it will be learning point for us.

Comment: Sorry, it's a `DictWriter` method that was added in Python 2.7, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=writeheader#csv.DictWriter.writeheader).

Comment: martineau: thanks and you are always the inspiration for me

Comment: I commented out that line and added a couple to accomplish the same thing in Python 2.6 — it should work because it's essentially how the method is implemented the [library source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/csv.py) for version 2.7.